# Is there a bound on $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{e^{x+y}+x+y} dx dy$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{e^{x+y}+x+y} dx dy
$$

For this integral, I am trying to find an upper bound and show it is thus finite, but do not even know if this form is. Is there a good way to check and or find a bound? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The integral diverges:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{e^{x+y}+x+y} dx dy\ge \int_{1}^{+\infty} \int_{1}^{+\infty} e^{e^{x+y}+x+y} dx dy\ge \int_{1}^{+\infty} \int_{1}^{+\infty} e^{e^{1+1}+1+1} dx dy=+\infty.$$